# C++ Не понимаю работу кода собственной функции C++

Tags: c++

Данная функция принимает значения указателя на первый эл-т массива символов.
По моей задумке, в цикле while должна подсчитываться длина массива, через арифметику указателей, но компилятор агрится на меня! Подчёркивая строку:
i = (int)((str)+j),
он говорит: Cast from pointer to smaller type 'int' loses information

Не понимаю почему не работает, буду благодарен за помощь!

```
int Length(char *str){
    int i=0, j=0;
    while((char)i!='\0'){
        i=0;
        i = (int)((str)+j);
        j++;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Если вы собираете в x64 конфигурации, то sizeof(char*) - 8 байт, а sizeof(int) - 4 байта. При приведении 8-байтового значения к 4-байтовому происходит потеря данных, о чем компилятор и предупреждает.

Comment: Компилятор правильно пишет, что попытка кастовать результат вычисления `((str)+j)` в `int` приводит к потере данных. Сомо возникновение необходимости что-то кастовать говорит о наличии пробелмы. А попытка кастовать указатель в `int`, который потом кастуется `char`, говорит о полном зашкваре. Попробуйте переписать эту функцию без кастов. Они тут ни к чему.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответы, проблему понял. Да, действительно есть потеря данных сначала в 4 байта, а потом ещё в 3. 
Я не могу понять, почему код не запускается, ведь это обычное явное преобразование типов. Да?

Comment: Ну в плане синтаксиса тут все правильно. Однако каст указателя с потерей данных - грубейшая ошибка, на которой разработчики компиляторов заостряют внимание.

Comment: Просто добавьте * - `i = (int)*(str+j);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип переменной `i` должен быть `char`. И при присваивание буквы от указателя нужно ещё разыменование `*`. Цикл должен был остановится после взятии значения строки, а не перед. Меняем на `do{ }while`

```
int Length(char *str){
    int  j=0;
    char i=0;
    do{
        // i=0;
        i = *((str)+j);
        j++;
    }while(i!='\0');
    return j-1;
}
```

*Преобразование типов, это последнее, что вы должны делать.*